# А нужно ли ставить здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В прошлую пятницу на пресс-конференции в Казани президент Республики Татарстан Рустам Нургалиевич Минниханов пригрозил Москве Золотой Ордой.

Нужны ли в этом предложении запятые?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, ни одной запятой не нужно.